# jQuery append only if the div hasn't previously been appended?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a scrolling text jQuery which should scroll the text of a few divs called `.vs-container`. I use them in a slideshow, and that is why the divs with the same ID´s are created multiple times in the codepen (which is how it is on my site).
But the problem is that the same div is appended time after time.

Is it possible to only append the div if it isn't already existing?

```
 function scrollText() {
   setInterval(function() {
           scrollAppend($(".vs-container"));
       }, 1500);
 };

 function scrollAppend(obj) {
    var $self = $(".vs-container");
    var lineHeight = $self.find(".vs-content:first-child").height();

    $(".vs-content:first-child").addClass("active");

     $self.animate({
         "marginTop": -lineHeight + "px"
     }, 300, function() {
         $self.css({
             marginTop: 0
         }).find(".active:first-child").appendTo($self);
     })
}

scrollText();
```

https://codepen.io/jockebq/pen/PVzpWR

Comment: `divs with the same ID´s are created multiple times` is invalid HTML - best to fix that first.

Comment: But they are displayed on different slides, I have just put them there for showing the issue. I want the scrolling text to continue between the slides.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a DOM element does not exist using if(!$('.test').length) {// do something here }

Comment: But is that possible without previously knowing the div's ID?